Residue of a removable singularity at inifinity
Exercise:
Find all the singularities of $$\frac{z^3e^{\frac{1}{z^2}}}{(z^2+4)^2},$$ classify them, and find each residue.
I found that $+2i, \ -2i$ are poles of order two. I was able to calculate their residues.
I found that in $0$ it has an essential singularity, and afaik to calculate that sort of residue I have to do the Laurent series and find $a_{-1}$ which can be complicated. So I decided to use that the sum of the residues is equal to minus the residue at infinity to calculate it.
Then I found that in infinity it has a removable singularity. Even though essential singularities have $0$ as residue, this doesn't apply to the ones in infinity but I can calculate them using that $Res(f(z), inf)=Res(\frac {1}{z^2} f(\frac 1 z), 0)$.
Usually in this sort of exercise I get that the function at that point is holomorphic so the residue is $0$ and I'm done, but in this one I got that:
$$\frac{1}{z^2} f(\frac 1 z ) = \frac{ e^{z^2}}{z(1+ z^2 4)^2}$$
And this is not holomorphic at $0$.
I have two questions:

$\frac{1}{z^2} f(\frac 1 z )$ has a simple pole in $z=0$, does $Res(f(z), inf)=Res(\frac {1}{z^2} f(\frac 1 z), 0)$ till holds? I mean, can I still calculate $Res(f(z), inf)$ calculating $Res(\frac {1}{z^2} f(\frac 1 z), 0)$ as I would usually calculate the residues of a simple pole?

To justify that it has an essential singularity at $z=0$ I didn't calculate the whole Laurent series, but I used that $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+4)^2} \sum \frac{z^{-2n-3}}{n!},$$
and that even thought that's not the whole Laurent series of the function at 0, it's clear that it has infinite negative powers so it has an essential singularity at 0. Is this valid or I can't escape but to calculate the whole Laurent series?



You  say "it's clear ...", but it's not clear to me how it's clear to you.  And the fact that you're asking is evidence that it's not so clear to you after all.
Exactly what is your reasoning for the fact that infinitely many of the coefficients of negative powers of $z$ in $f(z)$ are nonzero?

This may help. If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic in a deleted neighbourhood of $0$ and neither has an essential singularity at $z=0$, then $f(z)/g(z)$ can't have an essential singularity there.
